# I'm trying to change the color of each of a set of buttons using C#/Visual studio but nothing happens

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-2012, designer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cameron_PickerillTrinitapoli_Assn1
{
    public partial class seasonalBttnChanger : Form
    {
        public seasonalBttnChanger()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Triggers when program first loads
        //Sets up
        private void bttnChanger_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Button> lstTxt = new List<Button>
            {
            bttnSpring, bttnSummer, bttnAutumn, bttnWinter
            };

            //Wiring up event handlers in run time
            foreach (Button txt in lstTxt)
            {
                txt.MouseEnter += button_MouseEnter;
                txt.MouseLeave += button_MouseLeave;
            }
        }

        // Sets up different background colors for TextBoxes
        //* Static values for the color of each button need
        //to be added.
        //**Not what I was trying to accomplish
        //**This needs to go somewhere else
        void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // Event handlers always pass the parameter "sender" in as an object.
                //  You have to downcast it back to the actual type.
                String bttnName = null;
                String bttnNameSpring = "Spring";
                String bttnNameSummer = "Summer";
                String bttnNameAutumn = "Autumn";
                String bttnNameWinter = "Winter";
                Button txt = (Button)sender;
               // stkColor.Push(txt.BackColor);
                //txt.BackColor = Color.Red;
                bttnName = txt.Name;

                if (bttnName == bttnNameSpring)
                {
                    txt.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                }
                else if (bttnName == bttnNameSummer)
                {
                    //txt.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    txt.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else if (bttnName == bttnNameAutumn)
                {
                    txt.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else if (bttnName == bttnNameWinter)
                {
                    txt.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:\n   " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Handler for mouse leaving the button
        void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Button txt = (Button)sender;
                //txt.BackColor = stkColor.Pop();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:\n   " + ex.Message);
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Alright, so I'm just trying to create a simple program that changes the background colors of these buttons to some plain colors when you mouse over them. I had the same thing working using TextBox, but I need to get it working with button. I changed everything over to use the Button class, and it seems to have all the same functionality, but now the program runs, but nothing happens when you mouse over the buttons.

I'm pretty new to c#, stack exchange, and only slightly less so to programming in general, so sorry if I'm dinking up on etiquette/formatting my questions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to reference your buttons title when you are actually calling the button name

Changing:

```
            String bttnName = null;
            String bttnNameSpring = "Spring";
            String bttnNameSummer = "Summer";
            String bttnNameAutumn = "Autumn";
            String bttnNameWinter = "Winter";
            Button txt = (Button)sender;
```

To:

```
                String bttnName = null;
            String bttnNameSpring = "bttnSpring";
            String bttnNameSummer = "bttnSummer";
            String bttnNameAutumn = "bttnAutumn";
            String bttnNameWinter = "bttnWinter";
```

Causes the code to work.

If you do infact want to use the "Spring", "Summer" etc reference than i would suggest changing

```
bttnName = txt.Name;
```

to

```
bttnName = txt.Text;
```

And ensure that the Text of the labels is set correctly

Comment: You're right, I did have a mismatch there and I fixed that. However It's still doing nothing on mouse-over.

Comment: I would check that the onload is firing correctly.

you appear to be calling a class seasonalBttnChanger but then running the onload on bttnChanger? is this correct for your setup?

Comment: You know, somethings nagging me about that, but I can't find a problem with it. I'm basing this on a piece of sample code for the class I'm taking with virtually the same setup, and this runs, and that runs, and I don't see any huge differences other than the change from TextBoxes to Buttons, that and that nothing happens in mine.

Comment: yeah, i took the code and tried it in a new win forms application and it deffently works once the mismatch is fixed. I am nearly cetain that the issue relates to the _load. try putting a breakpoint on the List<Button> lstTxt = new List<Button> line and see if it is triggered when the program runs. If it isnt then you will need to fix that. in visual studio it should auto generate the onload method when you double click on the background of the form in the designer. if it creates an empty method you can move the load code there.

Comment: Alright, I got it working by double clicking the background in designer then copy-pasting the rest of my code into the automatically generated loader, thanks.

Comment: No worries, if you have a look in the form designer(expand the form item in the right and open the *.Designer.cs file) there should be a line like    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); this is what sets the onload reference. by double clicking  the background this would have been autogenerated for you.